# I have a google Forms that needs to have duplicates removed and statistics updated. Can this be done?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google form that was used for award votes and nominations.  Specifically, each question contained drop-down value and the voters each selected an option from the list.  At the end of the form, they were prompted to enter their email addresses.

Google Forms provides a wonderful pie chart summary of which selections had the highest entries.  However, some voters voted twice.  I removed the duplicate entries from the associated Google Sheets document, however, it did not update the tallies from within the Google Forms view of the voter questionnaire.

What is the proper way to strip duplicates, based off of a given criteria and update the form results?

Comment: it kinda does not make sense what you are after. the proper way is to filter google sheets spreadsheet and nullify duplicates there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a report view to re-display the replies elsewhere, omitting all but the first (or last) entry sent with the same email address. Edit your question if that's the approach you need to take- but it sounds like you're actually willing to delete the entries themselves. *Sheets* is a great way to view and analyze responses, but you can mangle, detach, or delete that Sheet of responses it offers to create. For data safety, among other reasons, the form entries are however always kept, with the form.

1. Open your form document—not the live version the respondents filled out, but the real one where you added the questions themselves.
2. From there, click over to the "Responses" section.
3. You'll likely start in the "Summary" view. Instead click over to see "Individual" responses.
4. Use the left and right arrows to locate each bad entry.
5. Click the "trash can" icon; the "Delete Response" button.

[see also the …[Manage Form Responses article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706) from the Help Center.]